# How do I force a <div> to be inline with the checkbox using only CSS?

Tags: html, css, inline

I have this, and I am not allowed to touch the HTML.

```html
<div id="dynamic001" class="div-container">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="dynamic002" id="dynamic003">
    <label for="dynamic003" class="label1">
    <div class="div-text" id="dynamic004">
 Sample Text
    </div> 
</div>
```

Is there any way to force **Sample Text** to be **inline** with the checkbox, using only CSS?

Comment: `.div-text { display: inline-block; }`?

Comment: will this help, https://lokesh-coder.github.io/pretty-checkbox ?

Answer (score 2):

Just add inline block to the div

```
  .div-text {
    display: inline-block
  }
```

```css
.div-text {
  display: inline-block
}
```

```html
<div id="dynamic001" class="div-container">
    <input type="checkbox" class="checkbox" name="dynamic002" id="dynamic003">
    <label for="dynamic003" class="label1">
    <div class="div-text" id="dynamic004">
 Sample Text
    </div> 
</div>
```